# How to have an integer string in an enum?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, enums

I know this is a proper enum:

```
Private Enum Months
  JANUARY = 1
  FEBRUARY = 2
  ...
End Enum
```

However, I want to have an enum where the string will solely be integers.

Example:

```
Private Enum ColumnCounts
  01 = 5
  02 = 4
  03 = 40
End Enum
```

The 01, 02 and 03 are all strings.  However, if I put "01", [01] or just 01, it tells me it expects the end of the Enum and that it isn't a valid statement.  Is there any way to accomplish this that I'm missing?  I even tried. 01.ToString(), but that wasn't an option.  :)  Any and all help is appreciated.  Thanks.

**Edit:**

```
Public Class Part

  Private Enum ColumnCounts
    f01 = 39
  End Enum

  Public Shared Function ValidateColumns(ByRef lstFields As List(Of String)) As Boolean
    For Each colCount In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(ColumnCounts))
      If colCount = "f" + lstFields(1) Then
        'Right here I need to compare the count of the list vs. the value of the enum.'
        Return True
      End If
    Next

    Return False
  End Function
End Class
```

Essentially, I didn't want to put the f in there, just wanted to do 01.  The way this will be called is:

```
Select Case (nRecordType)
  Case "01"
    ...
  Case "02"
    ...
  Case "03"
    Return Part.ValidateColumns(_lstFields)
End Select
```

Because I'm not making an instance of it and not calling a constructor, there's no way to autopopulate a Dictionary.  And I don't want to convert to integer so I'm not going to do an array.  That is just in case eventually the value gets above 99 and the next value would be A0.  I'm trying to think of easy future changes to this and backwards compatability.  If you need more explanations, let me know.

**Edit 2:**

This is what I've done now and I think it should work:

```
Public Class Part

  Private Shared columnCounts As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

  Public Shared Function ValidateColumns(ByRef lstFiels As List(Of String)) As Boolean
    InitializeColumnDictionary()

    Return lstFields.Count = columnCounts(lstFields(1))
  End Function

  Private Shared Sub InitializeColumnDictionary()
    columnCounts.Add("01", 39)
  End Sub
End Class
```

I'm not at a point where I can test it right now so I can't verify that it's going to do what I want to, but it doesn't give me an error when I build it so I'm crossing my fingers.

Comment: What is an "integer string"? It's either an Integer _or_ a string, not both.

Comment: @Oded - I meant essentially a string made solely of integers.  I'm taking a string from a file, splitting it, and using a field to determine the column count.

Comment: @XstreamNsanity: it sounds like you'd be better of using a dictionary lookup instead of an enum.  If you're reading a string from a file then you'd have to parse that into an enum value anyway, which isn't very tidy.

Comment: why dont' you use an array instead?   
Dim ColumnCounts As Integer() = New Integer() {0, 5, 4, 40}

Comment: @Oops - Check out my last update.

Comment: I think you’re fundamentally misunderstanding what enums are there for. Your code doesn’t need enums at all, by the way.

Comment: As the others have said, using an enum here for this purpose is not a good idea.

Comment: @Konrad and jimplode - Do you have an idea as to a better way to accomplish this then?  Essentially, the second field of a list of fields is a record format.  A format can have x number of columns.  If there are 5 different formats, I want to be able to make sure I validate against the proper format.  However, I want to avoid (for no extremely good reason) instantiating an object to accomplish this.

Comment: @Konrad and jimplode - Should I just make an initialize function that adds values to a dictionary?  I don't know why I didn't think of it before.

Comment: I don't agree with: "Because I'm not making an instance of it and not calling a constructor, there's no way to autopopulate a Dictionary". You can declare a dictionary and populate it if it's null/nothing in your static method.

Comment: @vulkanino - I said that because I've tried to initialize a Dictionary and give it values at initialization but it wouldn't let me.  However, I made another update to my post and hope that will work.  I'm not at a point where I can test it right now (other errors from other files) but I'm crossing my fingers.

Comment: IIRC [01] worked just fine in VB6... :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integers alone are NOT valid identifiers.
Why would you want to call 01 an identifier?
Prefix the enum elements with a letter, and you're done:

```
i01,
i02
...
```

edit as per your editing:
declare a static dictionary and populate it, if it's null, in your static method:

```
private static void yourMethod()
        {
            if (ColumnCounts == null)
            {
                ColumnCounts = new Dictionary<String, int>();
                ColumnCounts.Add("01", 39);
                ColumnCounts.Add("02", 45);
                ColumnCounts.Add("03", 12);
                ColumnCounts.Add("04", 0);
            }




        }



        private static Dictionary<String, int> ColumnCounts = null;
```

Comment: I'm taking a string from a file, splitting it, and using a field to determine the column count.  The string for that field could be 01, 02, etc. and I don't want to convert it to an integer because we don't know if in the future it will overflow the two places allotted for it.

Comment: I'll be accepting this one as the answer since it's what I'll have to go with and it was the first answer of this sort.

Comment: still I don't get it. you want to compare a string with an enum description? maybe you don't need an enum for that, but a dictionary to map a string to an integer.

Comment: I'm going to update my post with an example.  Check it out in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Enum elements are identifiers; and identifiers must start with a letter (or underscore). So, I am sorry, but this is not possible.

Note: corrected start characters after a comment.

Comment: Not quite accurate - an identifier can start with an underscore, for example.

Comment: :(  I so hope you're wrong, but this is what I was thinking as well.  Might be best just to use a dictionary or something.

Comment: @Dan - lol.  Nice, but I think he meant any non-numeric character.  Even then, I don't think slashes or asterisks would work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [valid identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711644.aspx) - which cannot begin with a number.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not possible to let an identifier of any kind start with an integer. You could do:

```
Private Enum ColumnCounts
  n01 = 5
  n02 = 4
  n03 = 40
End Enum
```

Answer (score 0):

For your enum you should use Column01 for the identifier. Later in your code, if you don't need the 01 portion, you can always call .ToString() and trim the Column portion out.

```
Private Enum ColumnCounts 
  Column01 = 5 
  Column02 = 4 
  Column03 = 40 
End Enum
```

Answer (score 0):

$.02

```
Private Enum foo As Integer
    _01 = 1
    _02 = 2
    _03 = 3
    _04 = 4
End Enum

Dim bar As IEnumerable(Of String) = (From membr In [Enum].GetNames(GetType(foo)) Select membr.Replace("_", ""))

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim nRecordType As String = "03"

    Select Case nRecordType
        Case bar(0)
            Debug.WriteLine("stop1")
            Stop
        Case bar(1)
            Debug.WriteLine("stop2")
            Stop
        Case bar(2)
            Debug.WriteLine("stop3")
            Stop
        Case bar(3)
            Debug.WriteLine("stop4")
            Stop
    End Select

End Sub
```